# How to iterate the input tag with-in a div tag and display multiple input tags based on inputdata

Tags: javascript, html

I have Name field and I want to display it multiple times based on input.

**Like:**

Name : Ash 
Name : Win

```js
var Property = [{
  "content": "Ash",
  "Name": "Name"
}, {
  "content": "Win",
  "Name": "Name"
}]
var data = Property;
for (var iter = 0; iter < data.length; iter++) {
  $("#Name").val(Property[iter].content);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div-id">
  <div class="form-row">
    <label for="Name"><i class="icon-tag"></i> Name </label>
    <input type="text" id="Name">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just inside the loop create the input element and add it to the `HTML`

```js
var Property = [{
  "content": "Ash", "Name": "Name"
}, {
  "content": "Win", "Name": "Name"
}]
var data = Property;
var elem = "";
for (var iter = 0; iter < data.length; iter++) {
  elem += '<label for="Name"><i class="icon-tag"></i> Name </label><input type="text" id="Name" value="'+Property[iter].content+'"><br/>';
}
$("#inp").html(elem);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "div-id">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div id="inp"> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery's `append()` to append HTML Elements inside a specific element like this:

```js
var Property = [{
  "content": "Ash", "Name": "Name"
}, {
  "content": "Win", "Name": "Name"
}]

Property.forEach(prop => {
  $("#form-row").append(`
  <label for="Name">
    <i class="icon-tag">${prop.Name}</i>
  </label>
  <input type="text" id="Name" value="${prop.content}"><br>
  `);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "div-id">
  <div id="form-row">
    
  </div>
</div>
```